# Rewrite sub folders to root with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite sub dirs like www.mydomain.com/views/pages/contact.php to www.mydomain.com/contact.php

What i've got so far is this.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /views/pages/$1
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.+)$ /views/pages/$1
```

That one works, but only with a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading slash doesn't work in .htaccess, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!views/pages/)(.*)$ /views/pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Yes thanks, but i coudn't do that, you are suppose to wait for 9 minutes.... But i did it now ;)